# Pointer to a pointer, how do I get values?

Tags: c, pointers

Lets say I have the following code,

```
typedef struct WordNode WordNode;
struct WordNode {
  int       freq;   // The frequency of the the word.
  char     *word;   // The word itself.
  WordNode *next;   // The next word node in the list.
};

struct WordSet {
  int       size;   // The number of elements in the set.
  WordNode *head;   // The starting node in the set.
};
```

After this, I've got some functions that initialize these structs. To prevent too much code in this post, I'm going to avoid posting those functions here.

Now, lets say I have the following,

```
  WordNode **p = wset->head; // can't change this line
```

Here, p is basically a pointer pointing to a pointer, correct?

And then, if I do this:

```
(*p) == NULL
```

This would return true if p is pointing to NULL, right?

Now, how would I get the word stored in wset->head?

Can I do this?

```
(*(*p))->word
```

And if I want p to point to the next WordNode, can I do this?

```
p = (*(*p))->next
```

I just want to know if all this is valid syntax so that I know I'm using pointers correctly.

Comment: `WordNode **p = wset->head;` -->> `WordNode **p = &wset->head; ` // should change this //BTW: what is `wset` ?

Comment: `WordNode **p = wset->head; ` ..compiler din't scream?

Comment: `WordNode **p = wset->head; ` doesn't compile, you cannot assign a `WordNode*` to a `WordNode**` variable. Maybe you meant `WordNode **p = &wset->head; `?

Comment: The compiler will compile (assigning a pointer to a pointer), but it will warn. However, this is dependent on the compilation settings. -Wall is always a good idea to compile with.

Answer (score 1):

Not really.  `(*(*p))->word` is a total dereferenciation. So it would either be `(*(*p)).word` or `(*p)->word`.

You can imagine it that way, that the `->`-Operator takes away one reference for you.

`obj->field` is the same as `(*obj).field`

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of simplicity, whenever I have to deal with double pointer and I need the value I all the time go via an intermediate variable

e.g.

```
WordNode **ptr2ptr = wset->head;
WordNode *ptr = *ptr2Ptr;
WordNode value = *ptr;
```

or to get the head:

```
WordNode head = ptr->head;
```

Now I'm just answering the question which is, how to access the value of a pointer to pointer. You must be careful that your wset->head contains actually a pointer to pointer which is normally not the case in a linked list the way I understand you are trying to do. This is also not the way you have defined your head member...